# Set Android to update only via WiFi?

Tags: nexus-5, ota-update

I own an Android phone (a Nexus 5, so it's "standard" Android) and use it with a very limited data plan. Sometimes it downloads huge updates over the mobile network, even though it's at home and could use our Wi-Fi.

I haven't caught it in the act, so I don't know if the updates are for the operating system itself or the apps.

Is there a setting I can use to configure the phone to download software updates exclusively via WiFi?

Comment: Do you mean a system update? (App updates can be set to WiFi-only in the Play store). System update does not respect that setting. This happened to me because I accepted the download when I was on WiFi but had run out of storage space. Later, when I was only on 3G, I watched a movie and deleted it. Now there was space, the update downloaded using my mobile data, while I was asleep! One solution would have been to disable mobile data, having noticed that the download failed and was likely to retry automatically. We could do with a better solution.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Probably, these are app's update, because if they are OS updates you would be asked to restart your device or install the update. To avoid auto update from app's:In the Play store app, swipe from the left edge to the right. Go to settings. Under the "General" list, select "Update app's automatically"and mark with a dot "Only through Wi-Fi"

Answer (score 8):

Also ;

**Goto** : `Settings -> About Phone -> Software Update -> Auto Update checked`

or other options for ***Enable Update*** with **Wifi** ...

---

**Edit :**

If you want to instead auto-update apps only when you're connected to a WiFi network, tap `Auto-update` apps over `Wi-Fi only` in the same pop-up.

[image]